# Using a var outside let - clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there any way in clojure to allow a var defined within a let structure to be used elsewhere in the namespace?

The problem that I am having is that I need two seperate values from the let.

For example if I have the code

```
    (defn example [x y z]
       (let [
          xy (* x y)
          xz (* x z)]
        xz))
```

Is there any way for me to use xy outside the let?

I should also note that xy and xz are just examples in this case, the real data sets are hash-maps and that I have tried using seperate functions to obtain each of sets seperately but because of the nature of the system that I am using this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: One clarification: a Var is a specific thing in clojure, and it is created by def forms. You could bind to a var in a let form `(do (def hello "world") (let [a #'hello] (alter-var-root a (constantly "world!")) (var-get a)))` but this has limited usefulness and would usually be perverse. let forms create bindings, bindings and vars are very different (and neither are variables).

Answer (score 2):

when you need multiple results from a single function, destructuring is useful

```
(defn example
  [x y z]
  (let [xy (* x y)
        xz (* x z)]
    [xy xz]))

(defn other-example
  (let [[xy xz] (example 1 2 3)]
    (println 'xy xy 'xz xz)))
```

Answer (score 1):

No, by definition the variables defined in a `let` will only be visible inside it. If you need a variable outside maybe you should use a global definition ... but in general that's not a good idea. How about passing around the values as parameters to the other functions that need it?

Comment: "...the variables defined in a `let`..." are indeed not even variables. Their values never change, though the symbol can be rebound.